# Error saving Core data from Web Service

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I am trying to save a bunch of 'Absences' from a  web service when we app initially launches (After login so can't do it in AppDelegate directly).

I have the following code which finds any existing records and deletes them before getting a new set.

The fetch is working fine (although nothing to fetch) as I see the printed line 'Nothing found'. But when I loop results from the web service, I get `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'AbsenceTypes' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'` thrown from the line `let newAbsence = AbsenceTypes(context: context)`

```
func getAndSaveAppointmentTypes(){


    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        absences = try context.fetch(AbsenceTypes.fetchRequest())
    } catch {
        print("Nothing found")
    }

    if !absences.isEmpty {
        for absence in absences {
            context.delete(absence)
        }
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    }


    let paramString : String = "My Param String"

    DataFunctions().getRequest(methodName: "MyMethod", parameters: paramString) { (result) -> () in

        for item in result {

            if item["Error"] != nil {

                handleError()

                return

            } else {

                let absenceID : String = item["id"] as! String
                let absenceDesc : String = item["Description"] as! String
                let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                let newAbsence = AbsenceTypes(context: context)
                newAbsence.absenceDesc = absenceDesc
                newAbsence.absenceId = absenceID
                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            }
            print("Absences saved")

        }

    }


}
```

So far I have:

- Checked and rechecked the Entity name in the data model and it matches.
- Cleaned and rebuilt the app
- Switched the module between Global Namespace and Current Project Module

Comment: Did you specify your model name when you set up your persistent container ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646262/core-data-nsmanagedobject-doesnt-have-a-valid-nsentitydescription

Comment: Yep and I've and rechecked the name. I have, however renamed it from the original name which makes me think there is perhaps an internal reference somewhere that needs clearing. That's why I cleaned and rebuilt.

Comment: Please show the code where you set up the persistent container

Comment: It's exactly the same as the linked post. Auto generated in AppDelegate when the project was created. I have just renamed the data model and changed the line `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyDataModel")`

Comment: Try using the original name for your model when you create the nspersistentcontainer

Comment: Still no luck. Ended up just creating a new datamodel and it works fine. I guess there is an internal reference somewhere that isn't getting changed